# Call to a member function format() on string error calling data from DB Laravel 10

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using Laravel 10

Edit page (View)

```
    <input type="date" id="date" name="date" class="form-control" 
    value="{{$event->date->format('Y-m-d')}}">
```

Model

```
    protected $casts = 
         'items' => 'array',
         'expired_at' => 'datetime',
     ];
    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $dates = ['date', 'expired_at'];
```

> Error: `call to a member function format() on string`

I want to show the date of my event that I added to DB before editing

Note: trying the solution I saw in the internet I added "expired_at" but the error persist

Comment: Move the date out of `$dates` and into `$casts`. [`$dates` is no longer a cast property](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/upgrade#model-dates-property)